# conversion type

Tags: c#, c++

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR buf[1024] ; // code from C++ dll
```

how to define above line of code in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typedef is just an alias for a type, another name.  No aliases in C#.  This declaration is otherwise somewhat equivalent to

```
 char[] buf = new char[1024];
```

You would use a plain char[] in a pinvoke declaration and pass an array that was allocated as shown above.  I would be cautious with this code, adding an identifier "buf" to the global namespace is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Without a definition of `WCHAR` there's no way to say anything about the code you posted. However, assuming that `WCHAR` is a typename of some sort, the code you posted is not a valid C++ code. It simply will not compile as C++ code.

At the same time you seem to claim that it comes from some "C++ dll". Most likely you didn't reproduce the original code correctly. Update the code, since in its current form it makes your question totally meaningless.

Comment: WCHAR is a very common (Windows?)  typedef/macro for Wide-char, a normal char in C#.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: If `WCHAR` is a typedef/macro for wide-char type, then the OP's declaration is invalid, since it already includes the `wchar_t` type explicitly. Yet the OP claims it came from valid code. The only hope for that code to be valid is if `WCHAR` stands for something else.

Comment: Andrey, on 2nd reading you're right, but it's still a Win.h thing.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have typedef, so you cannot write that line in C#. Perhaps there is a solution, if you tell us what you want to do. But the answer to your question is: not at all!

Comment: the previous line typed in C++ and i need to use Pinvoke in C#

Comment: @user689851: The line you provided is *not* C++, once again.